tell me any of his secrets
a. I can't make him tell me any of his secrets.
Can't this mean two things:

I can't make him tell me even a single one of his secrets.

I can only make him tell me some of his secrets, but not just any of them.


Many thanks


I can't make him tell me any of his secrets.

This would mean the first one.  He wouldn't tell you a single one.
To mean the second one, you could say

I can't make him tell me certain of his secrets.

Collins Dictionary explains certain in its second sense 2:

quantifier
When you refer to certain of a group of people or things, you are referring to some particular members of that group.
[formal] They'll have to give up completely on certain of their studies. [+ of]

Edit
or

I can't make him tell me all his secrets.


Or I can't make him tell me all his secrets (implying 'he will tell me some but not all of them').

Thanks, @Kate Bunting. Yes, agreed.  I've added your point.
